# get json from another domain that requires user authentication

Tags: php, json, ajax

I want to get a JSON response with ajax request from another site, but the site requires user authentication to acces to the JSON resource.

How should my AJAX request should be structured to send login and password information with ajax request and get JSON response?

Comment: are you the owner of the site who needs credentials ?

Comment: @singebatteur  no , but i have an account on this site(login&password)

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @JasonCust i mean  JSON representation

Comment: I was mentioning it in jest as a large number of people make that mistake hence the [Princess Bride quote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wujVMIYzYXg). :D

Comment: I guess you should contact the site's staff.. what site is it ?